# How to swap bit position value 12 34 56 78?

Tags: c

Ex: Like binary value 1010 then after swap pair bit position value 0101

Comment: Do you want the result to be 87654321 or 21436587?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned char swapped = ((original & 85) << 1) | ((original & 170) >> 1);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
int pairwise_bit_swap(int a) {
    return ((a & 0x55555555L) << 1) | ((a & 0xAAAAAAAAL) >> 1);
}
```

Comment: +1.  Very simple code using a reasonably clear technique.  As a portability note, it is possible that some compilers may use an int with a sufficiently large range that this code will cause the int to be truncated.

Comment: Beware that right shifting a signed integer will propagate the sign bit. This means that if a is negative the first bit of the result will be 1, regardless the second!
I suspect you want unsigned int (that is, you are interested in the bits pattern, not in the value they represent in 2's complement). If you really, really need a to be int, you can simply cast it on the fly:
((a & 0x55555555) << 1) | ((((unsigned int)a) & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1)

or clear it "manually":
((a & 0x55555555) << 1) | (((a & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1) & 0x7FFFFFFF)

Comment: Also note that this will only work on a 32 bits int. The fact that you put L at the end is of no help if int is 64 bits!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method mentioned [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingBitsXOR)

Comment: I need to swap pair of bit positions like the pair to swap 1st and 2nd bit position values similarly bit positions 34, 56, 78, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the >> to shift bits.

Answer (score 0):

If u want swap odd position bits to even position(Like swap pair bits 1 2 , 3 4 , 5 6 and 7 8 )

unsigned char a,x,y,z;
a = 2+4+8+128;
x = a & 170;
y = a & 85;
z = (x>>1)|(y<<1);

Z is the answer.

Similarly we can swap 16 bit and so on. Please, work out the above sample scenario...

Answer (score 0):

```
((x << 1) & 0xAAAAAAAA) |( (x >>1) & 0x55555555)
```

where x in the number.